# VHDL - testbench hangs due to a problem with nested for loop

Tags: vhdl

I encountered a problem when trying to simulate a D flip-flop design.

Here's a snippet of my testbench code:

```
d_ff_tb_process: process
begin
    for D_idx in std_logic range '0' to '1' loop
        input <= D_idx;
        for S_idx in std_logic range '0' to '1' loop
            set <= S_idx;
            for R_idx in std_logic range '0' to '1' loop
                reset <= R_idx;
                wait for 10 ns;
            end loop;
        end loop;
    end loop;

    wait;
end process d_ff_tb_process;

clock <= not clock after 3 ns;
```

And here's the simulation:

[image: 1]]

**Question:**
As you can see, the simulation halts at 70 ns, even though it should stop at 80 ns (simulation time in ModelSim is set to 100 ns). I believe that for some reason `wait for 10 ns;` is not being executed when `D_idx = '1'`, `S_idx = '1'`, and `R_idx = '1'`. Why is this happening and how do I fix it? Thanks

Comment: @dave-tweed I'd disagree with putting this question on hold as off-topic; I see Verilog questions on EE.SE all the time, so why not VHDL simulation questions?

Comment: Here's a question, and a potential answer. Question: why does your simulation ever stop? The statement `clock <= not clock after 3ns;` should loop forever and the simulation would run forever. Potential answer: VHDL simulation ends when there are no more events to process. At the very end of your sim we do see `R` transitioning high; the only reason the simulation doesn't run to 80ns is because there are *no more events to process* (no more signal transitions); the fact that there is a `wait for 10ns;` statement in there is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Mr.Snrub: The OP explicitly requested migration to StackOverflow; evidently, that migration was rejected, which leaves the question "on hold" here. I've reopened it. BTW, your hypothesis doesn't hold water -- the clock statement alone generates future events forever.

Comment: Did you test your hypothesis by changing wait 10ns to a different time?

Comment: @DaveTweed I mentioned exactly that in my comment, i.e. the OP's complaint is that "the simulation stops at 70ns", but like I said (and you also said) the simulation runs forever. So there is something going on beyond what he has posted. But *if* the simulation is in fact stopping at 70ns (i.e. for whatever reason the clock isn't making the sim run forever) then my proposed answer would hold.

Comment: @Toor nope haven't tested it -- don't have a ModelSim install at home. But that *is* how VHDL simulations work -- run until there are no more events to process, and then stop. A `wait` statement has no effect on the simulation if there are no events after it.

Comment: How did you run the simulation?   `run -all`  or `run 70 ns`?   Historically, running something like this with `run -all` is going to run forever.   However, maybe they have added a clock detect of some sort.   To test this out, just before the wait, add an `input <= not input ;`  and rerun the simulation.

Answer (score 1):

*Transferred and expanded from comments*

ModelSim uses event-driven simulation. Reference page 22 of [this presentation](http://www.tkt.cs.tut.fi/kurssit/50200/S15/Kalvot/Lecture%209%20-%20Simulators.pdf). It processes all events (changes in signals) at a certain point in time, then advances to the next point in time where there are events to process, and repeats this loop until there are no more remaining events to be processed. This means two things related to your simulation:

1. It should have never stopped.
2. ...but if it did stop, then yes it should have stopped at 70ns instead of 80ns.

## It should have never stopped

Your statement `clock <= not clock after 3 ns;` creates an infinite sequence of events. Each time a `clock <= not clock` event gets processed, there will be another one waiting 3ns later, and that will go on forever.

But, for some reason, your simulation did stop. I suspect there is something else in the portion you did't post in your question. So, ...

## But if it did stop, then yes it should have stopped at 70ns instead of 80ns

So the simulation time only advances when there is another event to process. If you walk through the logic of your simulation code (and unwrap the loops), then the final few steps are "drive reset high", "wait for 10ns", then "done". This means that the last *event* occurs at 70ns. That final `wait for 10ns;` statement does nothing to advance the simulation time.

On your waveforms we do see `R` transitioning to a high level right at the very end of the simulation. The only thing that didn't happen in the simulation is the signals sitting in an idle state for another 10ns, but per the above that's not supposed to happen anyway.